# Oracle query over db link loses index and performs full table scan

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that has a good execution plan...
[image]

When I take this query and run it over a database link I lose the index in the execution plan...

[image]

Is there any way to get this query to keep the index?

regards

Comment: What happens if you alias the remote table as, `SELECT /*+ DRIVING_SITE(a) */ FROM (SELECT * FROM thead@ORPMYRP.CMLTD.NET.AU a WHERE business_part_date=trunk(sysdate) and processed_ind='N');`?

Comment: if there was join between local and remote table i would use hint use_nl like here: http://msutic.blogspot.com/2012/03/tuning-distributed-query-using-usenl.html...

Comment: Does the table "thread@ORPMYRP.CMLTD.NET.AU" have indexes? Anyway, I were you I would refuse using hints, if oracle has fresh statistics it will choose the best execution plan

Comment: yes. As per the first screen shot above there is an index

Answer (score 3):

Your query has to be this way only,

```
SELECT  /*+ DRIVING_SITE(thead) */ *
    FROM thead@ORPMYRP.CMLTD.NET.AU 
    WHERE business_part_date=trunk(sysdate) 
     and processed_ind='N';
```

OR use a [Global hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#27647) like below, when subquery is in place.

```
 SELECT /*+ DRIVING_SITE(a.thead) */ *
 FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM thead@ORPMYRP.CMLTD.NET.AU 
    WHERE business_part_date=trunk(sysdate) 
    and processed_ind='N') a
```

When you use like below,

```
 SELECT /*+ DRIVING_SITE(a) */ *
 FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM thead@ORPMYRP.CMLTD.NET.AU 
    WHERE business_part_date=trunk(sysdate) 
    and processed_ind='N') a
```

The hint gets useless as the alias name a is no more meaningful to be useful in HINT as it doesnt refer a table but a subquery's result. 
And entire rows of AU table in remote db is sent to the local now. So it means, index is of no use now, so oracle goes for full table scan.

Comment: The hint syntax is correct but I'm not sure if [DRIVING_SITE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50704) is the correct hint here.  That hint appears to only be designed for joins.  A hint like `INDEX(a.thead)` should work.  Although there's still the interesting question of why the plans are different when this statement is run locally or remotely.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Both of you suggested solutions did NOT work and I end up with the same undesired partition range scan plan